# Yii2: Simultaneous authentication between frontend and API

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've turned the backend into an API. And the API controllers have HttpBasicAuth type authentication.

The problem is that even after authentication in the frontend, whenever a request is made to the API, the authentication window appears.

How can I do so that when the user authenticates in the frontend, is not requested again the username and password of access when a request is made to the API?

Example a controller in API:

```
class CategoryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\models\Category';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'authMethods' => [
                [
                    'class' => HttpBasicAuth::className(),
                    'auth' => function($username, $password) {
                        $out = null;
                        $user = \common\models\User::findByUsername($username);
                        if ($user != null) {
                            if ($user->validatePassword($password)) $out = $user;
                        }
                        return $out;
                    }
                ],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think API and the website is two different areas, just imagine website and mobile app. In my point of view user must login to these 2 areas separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called sharing sessions. It also depends on if your tier apps (frontend and api) are both in the same domain. If it is, configure your frontend and api settings (`<app>/frontend/config/main.php` and `<app>/api/config/main.php`) as follow:

```
'components' => [
    ...
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-shared',
    ],
    ...
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-shared', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    ...
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'advanced-shared',
    ],
    ...
```

It means you save cookies and session with the same name, so that when you login in frontend, and go to backend/api, the backend side fetches same cookies, therefore you'll be detected as authenticated user.

Here one important note, in order to `enableAutoLogin` work for both tiers, you should set same `cookieValidationKey` for both `main-local.php` settings. You can just set them manually, or edit `init.php` file to generate one cookieValidationKey for all tiers. (Just make sure you know what you're doing).

By the way, I think it's not a good idea to make simultaneous authentication between `frontend` and `api`. If it's `frontend` and `backend` then it's still bearable, but `api` interaction is different compared to `frontend`.
I suggest to use headers like `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.. You can get more information about it here [Yii2 Rest Authentication](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-authentication)

### Update

I assume this is what you need.. Create a class, i.e. `ApiAuth` in `common/components` folder and paste the following code:

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

use yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth;

class ApiAuth extends HttpBasicAuth
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function authenticate($user, $request, $response)
    {
        if ($user->identity) {
            return $user->identity;
        }

        return parent::authenticate($user, $request, $response);
    }
}
```

This class extends from `yii\filters\auth\HttpBasicAuth`. Before calling a browser prompt it checks whether `user->dentity` is populated. If so, no promt is required.

In your Controller behavior replace `HttpBasicAuth` with `ApiAuth` class:

```
use common\components\ApiAuth;
...
'authMethods' => [
    [
        'class' => ApiAuth::className(),
        'auth' => function($username, $password) {
        ...
```

Comment: Yes this way I got both frontend and api (backend) to recognize the authentication. But when I make an ajax request to the controller I get a browser prompt to re-authenticate.

Comment: @Giest look for my update. I extended Yii Http authentication class.

Answer (score 0):

As the user is already authenticated, then I just set the "AccessControl" for connected users. If they are not connected they will receive code 403 instead of 401.

This solves the problem:

```
class CategoryController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'api\models\Category';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['access'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```